# Event is Undefined in IE works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have onKeypress Event in Text Box This Works in FireFox, does not in IE

event is passed as undefined in IE

```
PriceInBox.onkeypress = function(event) { return moZoltarCurrent.evt_checkForInt(event); }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to normalize the Event interface, as IE [doesn't pass it along](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html) as a parameter, but uses a global variable:

```
PriceInBox.onkeypress = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    return moZoltarCurrent.evt_checkForInt(event);
};
```

Comment: This long-standing irritation is *finally* fixed with the event model changes in IE9 Standards Mode.

Comment: IE9 really does look to be making up a lot of ground standards-wise.