# Need Help to replace cancelBubble javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i need some help with my Javascript, The problem is that my JavaScript code is not working properly on Internet explorer 8 as well as Internet explorer 7,it works properly on Chrome. it is giving error saying that:

***"Unable to set property 'cancelBubble' of undefined or null reference
File: treelist.js, Line: 24, Column: 5".***

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/67/)

```
var dataSource = ({
    "Pen": ({
        "Cello": ({
            "C2": ({}),
            "C1": ({})
        }),
            "Parker": ({
            "P2": ({}),
            "P1": ({})
        })
    })
});
 var traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                var classNames = this.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    this.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    this.className = this.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                e.cancelBubble = true;
      //        e.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[prop]).length) {
                console.log(Object.keys(obj[prop]).length + "  " + Object.keys(obj[prop]));
                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dvList1").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));

}
```

---

Thank you

Comment: Did you even look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.cancelBubble)

Comment: I just know looked at the docs,"cancelBubble is set to false by default." but i am confused how to use it. Need Some help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3774468/218196, for the other part of your problem (`e` being undefined). I recommend to read the articles about event handling on quirksmode.org: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. They also explain the differences between browsers.

Answer (score -1):

```
var Objectkeys = function(obj){
        a = []
        for(var prop in obj){
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
             a.push(prop);
            }
        };
        return a;
    },
    traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                var classNames = this.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    this.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    this.className = this.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                var e = window.event;
                e.cancelBubble = true;
    //          if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
            }
            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Objectkeys(obj[prop]).length) {
                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    },
    sortedObject = function (obj) {
        document.getElementById("dvList2").innerHTML = "";
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;
        var keys = Objectkeys(obj).sort();
        for (prop in keys) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(keys[prop]));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                var classNames = this.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    this.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    this.className = this.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                var e = window.event;
                e.cancelBubble = true;
    //          if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (typeof obj[keys[prop]] == "object" && Objectkeys(obj[keys[prop]]).length) {
                li.appendChild(sortedObject(obj[keys[prop]]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dvList1").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
    document.getElementById("hlGSL").onclick = function(){document.getElementById("dvList2").appendChild(sortedObject(dataSource));}
//  document.getElementById("hlGSL").addEventListener("click",function(){document.getElementById("dvList2").appendChild(sortedObject(dataSource))},false);

}
```